# cpp-netlib install visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2013, installation, cpp-netlib

The reason that i open this topic is because the information about setting up the cpp-netlib is quite tricky.The documentation that i used to follow the steps is bit confused, i have to mention that i'm a beginner with this open source libraries, and before asking what have i done wrong here is what i did:

1.Before setting cpp-netlib v 11.0 i installed boost.I run it their example by adding the headers necessarily, so far everything looks good.

2.I had setup the path BOOS_ROOT for cpp-netlib

3.After i unzipped the cpp-netlib file i used cmake to build it.I also noticed that there are more CMakeList files, so i use the first one.It didn't worked... Next i looked in the examples (..\cpp-netlib-0.11.0-final\libs\network\example) and noticed a second one.This one worked.

4.After i created the solution i saw more examples.The one that i'm interested is hello_wolrd_server, to test that everything works fine.

5.I added the headers and build it and i get the following log.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ZERO_CHECK, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>------ Build started: Project: atom_reader, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
3>------ Build started: Project: hello_world_async_server_with_work_queue, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
4>------ Build started: Project: hello_world_client, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
5>------ Build started: Project: hello_world_server, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
6>------ Build started: Project: http_client, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
7>------ Build started: Project: rss_reader, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
8>------ Build started: Project: simple_wget, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
9>------ Build started: Project: twitter_search, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>  atom.cpp
2>d:\data\genericsearchengine\cpp-netlib-0.11.0-final\libs\network\example\atom\atom.hpp(12): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/network/protocol/http.hpp': No such file or directory
2>  main.cpp
2>d:\data\genericsearchengine\cpp-netlib-0.11.0-final\libs\network\example\atom\atom.hpp(12): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/network/protocol/http.hpp': No such file or directory
2>  Generating Code...
8>  simple_wget.cpp
8>D:\Data\GenericSearchEngine\cpp-netlib-0.11.0-final\libs\network\example\simple_wget.cpp(17): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/network/protocol/http/client.hpp': No such file or directory
3>  hello_world_async_server_with_work_queue.cpp
3>D:\Data\GenericSearchEngine\cpp-netlib-0.11.0-final\libs\network\example\http\hello_world_async_server_with_work_queue.cpp(9): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/network/include/http/server.hpp': No such file or directory
9>  search.cpp
9>D:\Data\GenericSearchEngine\cpp-netlib-0.11.0-final\libs\network\example\twitter\search.cpp(7): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/network/protocol/http/client.hpp': No such file or directory
6>  http_client.cpp
6>D:\Data\GenericSearchEngine\cpp-netlib-0.11.0-final\libs\network\example\http_client.cpp(3): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/network/protocol/http/server.hpp': No such file or directory
4>  hello_world_client.cpp
7>  rss.cpp
5>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc120-mt-gd-1_56.lib'
4>D:\Data\GenericSearchEngine\cpp-netlib-0.11.0-final\libs\network\example\http\hello_world_client.cpp(14): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/network/protocol/http/client.hpp': No such file or directory
7>d:\data\genericsearchengine\cpp-netlib-0.11.0-final\libs\network\example\rss\rss.hpp(12): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/network/protocol/http.hpp': No such file or directory
7>  main.cpp
7>d:\data\genericsearchengine\cpp-netlib-0.11.0-final\libs\network\example\rss\rss.hpp(12): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/network/protocol/http.hpp': No such file or directory
7>  Generating Code...
10>------ Skipped Build: Project: ALL_BUILD, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
10>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 8 failed, 0 up-to-date, 1 skipped ==========
```

Before asking what i'm doing it wrong, i want to mention that cpp-netlib talks about [3 libs](http://cpp-netlib.org/0.11.0/getting_started.html#building-on-windows).I couldn't find theme.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check that include directories are specified properly.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem.It seemed that boost had no libraries included.

Comment: you can post a solution then, in case someone bumps into the same thing

Comment: I've notice that the solution is just a quick fix for my sample server.What i've done i used the prebuilt binaries for boost.However if i use cpp-netlib in another project it's still not working.The clinet code is here (http://cpp-netlib.org/0.11.0/index.html#hello-world).I assume that those 3 libs mentioned in the topic are the problem.The reason i'm saying this because i get a LNK 2019 error.I found what i have to do (http://cpp-netlib.org/0.11.0/index.html#hello-world) and now i need 3 static libraries, the one that are missing.To do this i have to build with cmake, but i got stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to build an Visual Studio project/solution for cpp-netlib if you follow the CMake instructions:

http://cpp-netlib.org/0.11.1/getting_started.html#building-on-windows

You should be able to generate the solutions using CMake's "Visual Studio" generator. This should look something like:

```
cd ~
mkdir cpp-netlib-build
cd cpp-netlib-build
cmake ../cpp-netlib-0.11.1 -G "Visual Studio 10 Win64"
```

This should produce the solution and project files for Visual Studio. You can find a list of CMake generators for the correct version of Visual Studio you're using here:

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/manual/cmake-generators.7.html